# Remove white space between dynamically created ImageViews Android

Tags: android

I have created imageViews (dynamically ) within a for loop in an Android Studio application.
Is there a way to remove/shorten the white space that is created?

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
            for(int i = 0; i < userKeys.size() + 1; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(userKeys.get(i).toString());

                ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
                image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(1000,1000));
                image.setMaxHeight(20);
                image.setMaxWidth(20);
                // Adds the view to the layout
                //layout.addView(image);
                layout.addView(image);
                Picasso.with(this).load("***************" + userKeys.get(i).toString()).into(image);
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `image.setAdjustViewBounds(true)` and `image.setScaleType(something suitable like CenterCrop)`

the `setAdjustViewBounds` is important if your bitmap is a different aspect to the view's width/height

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html for more

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

> centerCrop()

like:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("*****" + userKeys.get(i).toString()).centerCrop().into(image);
```

There are other options available too like:

`.centerInside()
.fit()`

Source: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Answer (score 0):

[image]

adding>    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/temp_image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

this worked for me